# I am not able to pull files from SFTP file source while I am able to connect through FileZilla

Tags: java, linux, unix, sftp

I am getting "**Failed to negotiate transport Component**" in the log. Does anybody have any idea what can be the cause, because it doesn't seem to be any code side issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
Failed to negotiate a transport component [aes192-cbc] [arcfour] [Unknown cause] 
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.B(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.C(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.processMessage(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.startTransportProtocol(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.Ssh2Client.connect(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Sounds like a cipher suite mismatch? If you are running a POSIX box, you can try using `scp -v localfile.txt user@remote.host:~/` instead, maybe that will help you debug this more

Comment: No, I am running in Windows Box, so it won't help . Any other suggestions ??

Comment: Not at the moment. There's not much to go on here.  If you can provide more information that would be helpful

Comment: Failed to negotiate a transport component [aes192-cbc] [arcfour] [Unknown cause]
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.B(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.C(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.processMessage(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.startTransportProtocol(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh2.Ssh2Client.connect(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
  at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(Unknown Source)

Comment: See this is the log which i am getting .

Comment: Ok yeah definitely a cipher suite issue, the `aes192-cbc` gives it away... not sure how to solve this with the info given...

Comment: What cipher does FileZilla end up using? Can you attach FileZilla log file? (a real log file, not the message log from GUI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server supports "arcfour" cipher only, while your client supports "aes192-cbc" only.

The j2ssh-maverick implements the "arcfour" too. You can enable it by using `JCEComponentManager.installArcFourCiphers`.

Though note that "arcfour" is a weak cipher and you should avoid it, if possible. Consider upgrading the server.